# Galois Action on Absolutely Irreducible Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, finite-fields, galois-extensions

Consider an absolutely irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_{q^r}$. Consider also $Gal(\mathbb{F}_{q^r}, \mathbb{F}_q)$. Is there any possibility that $\sigma(f(x))$ remains an absolutely irreducible polynomial where $\sigma \in Gal(\mathbb{F}_{q^r}, \mathbb{F}_q)$ different from identity?

To be more clear, my question is that when we take a function $p(x) \in \mathbb{F}_q [x]$ and suppose that $p(x)= \prod_{\sigma \in Gal(\mathbb(F)_{q^r}, \mathbb{F}_q)} \sigma(h(x))$ where $h(x)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{q^r}[x]$ which is absolutely irreducible. I am wondering that can $\sigma(h(x))$ be absolutely irreducible under some condition on $\sigma$? If so, what are the conditions on $\sigma$?

Comment: $f(x)=x+1$ is fixed by $\sigma$.

Comment: Since $x+1$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_q \[ x\]$, so it does, yes.

Comment: My question was like that, take a function $p(x) \in \mathbb{F}_q [x]$ and suppose that $p(x)= \prod_{\sigma \in Gal(\mathbb(F)_{q^r}, \mathbb{F}_q)} \sigma(h(x))$ where $h(x)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{q^r}[x]$ which is absolutely irreducible. I am wondering that can $\sigma(h(x))$ be absolutely irreducible under some condition on $\sigma$? I am sorry if I asked in a wrong way at the beginning.

Comment: What does absolutely irreducible mean here? Did you mean $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$? Every one-variable polynomial splits over the algebraic closure. $\sigma$ extends to an automorphism of $\overline{k}$ then of $\overline{k}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ so it sends the irreducibles to themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f \in \mathbb{F}_{q^r}[x]$ be absolutely irreducible.

Given a polynomial $g$ and an automorphism $\sigma$ of a field containing the parameters of $g$ (eg a global automorphism), allow me to write $g^\sigma : x \mapsto \sigma(g(x))$. In other words $g^\sigma(x) := \sigma(g(x))$.

For any global automorphism $\sigma \in Gal(\operatorname{acl}(\mathbb{F}_{q}), \mathbb{F}_q)$, the polynomial
$f^\sigma$ is also absolutely irreducible.

To see this, notice that if $f^\sigma$ factors, say $f^\sigma = P \cdot Q$ where $P, Q$ have coefficients in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$, then $f = (f^\sigma)^{\sigma^{-1}} = (P \cdot Q)^{\sigma^{-1}} = P^{\sigma^{-1}} \cdot Q^{\sigma^{-1}}$. Moreover, $\deg(P) = \deg(P^{\sigma^{-1}})$ and $\deg(Q) = \deg(Q^{\sigma^{-1}})$.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @nomadd if this answers your question, fell free to accept the answer and/or upvote it :)

Comment: You need first to extends $\sigma$ to $\overline{\Bbb{F}}_q$ (obvious for the Frobenius, at bit less over other fields) as it is $P^{\sigma^{-1}}$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @reuns This is perfectly correct, one needs to adress this technical issue. I used the abuse of notation consisting in considering $\sigma$ given as a global automorphism. This abuse of notations is consistent (eg the map $\bar{\sigma} \mapsto f^\sigma$ is well defined) and very convenient when doing Galois theory. :)

Comment: @reuns Besides, given $\sigma \in Gal(\mathbb{F}_{q^r}, \mathbb{F}_q)$ there is a very natural candidate to expand $\sigma$ since $\sigma$ is a power of the Frobenius. 

I now edited the proof, thank you! :-)